# Stack Overflow app is completely blank

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, stack-overflow-app

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this question, but I really need to ask - what's wrong with the Stack Overflow app?

I'm using Nexus 5X with Android 7.1.2. App version - Current (1.0.1)

As you can see, this is how the app looks in my phone:

---

**Answers in a question:**

[image: Answers in a question 1: The Question going up too much when scrolling]
[image: Answers in a question 2: After a lot of scrolling, you can find the answers]

**Main page:**

[image: Main page 1: Guess the question 1]
[image: Main page 2: Guess the question 2]

**Members area(?):**

[image]

Just note: The Stack Exchange app works, and shows everything correct. The problem is with [Stack Overflow app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.stackoverflow).

Comment: Hmm this is.... strange. Mind telling me if the same thing happens in 1.0.2? What is your device's locale?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi I haven't tried the new version yet. My device locale is Israel

Comment: it seems to be both a font-based issue an a right-to-left text thing -- i'm looking into this.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Update: I did tried the new version, and it looks the same

Comment: Finally figured this out! It was one of our library packages being marked as `supportsRtl` in its manifest, which was making it all the way through to the app's manifest. Fixed in the next update, I'll post an answer when that's rolling out.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi will it effect on all stack-exchange apps?

Comment: Yep, it'll be fixed on both apps.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is finally fixed and live, sorry for the long delay!

The fix is in version 1.0.4 of the Stack Overflow app (and 1.0.95 of the Stack Exchange app), which should be live on the Play Store now (or within a few hours).

Comment: I can see it now - It's finally fixed. Thank you very much.